# Sending logs from ECS Fargate into Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logging, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have multiple containers deployed on ECS Fargate, that send logs to CloudWatch. I also want to send this application (containers) logs to Elasticsearch (not Amazon Elasticsearch Service).

Is it possible to collect logs directly from the ECS cluster instead of CloudWatch using the elastic agent ?

My first approach was to deploy a elastic agent in this ECS Fargate cluster, which is managed using Fleet Server. This agent has a policy with a ES integration [AWS](https://docs.elastic.co/en/integrations/aws), that collects logs from [Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.elastic.co/integrations/aws/cloudwatch) which is working but I want to not be dependent of CloudWatch.